# how to close trace 32 application itself through cmm command?

Tags: python, command, exit, trace32

I load and execute a cmm script inside trace32 application using bmm commands.
when the execution is over i need to close the entire t32 application window itself (similar to File -> Exit) using **cmm command** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close the PowerView main window use TRACE32 command `QUIT`

Comment: Thanks! its working but how to control errors like "MMU Translation failed" while running a cmm script and jump to next command in the script ?

Comment: i wrote command: on error GOTO
(
 QUIT  

) which is working but how to make sure on error event is triggered ? Is it possible to return any value to command prompt which is calling this cmm script? i.e return value outside cmm script to python script or command prompt

Comment: In general an `ON ERROR` handler should be placed in you script before the action takes place in which you assume an error. Check the `PMACRO` window, to see if the `ON ERROR` handler is present on the PRACTICE stack. If the handler is active it should trigger on any error. If you're facing problems here, I think you should open a new case and post a minimal example of your script and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To get a return value to the command line which called the TRACE32 application (t32m*.exe) use the QUIT command with it's optional argument. E.g. `QUIT 5` passes 5 to the caller. You can also use the `OPEN`, `WRITE` and `CLOSE` commands to write data from a PRACTICE script (cmm-script) to a file and read the data then from your python script. However if you want to control test sequences from a python script you should consider to use the TRACE32 remote API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417942 (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883140)